# How can I reorder <ul> elements horizontally aligned in navbar based on screen size (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

In my html page the elements are properly fixed in the navbar.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

when the screen is smaller the elements are in vertical

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have managed to decrease the size of `navbar` but the elements are in vertical. I need the `li` elements horizontally aligned in `navbar` with small font size. The code I used for decreasing the navbar is given below.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    height: 54px
  }
  .navbar .nav ul {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: smaller;
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-primary">

  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x35" width="40" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-1 h1">Byte Program</span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-3 mt-3 ">

      <li class="nav-item ">
        <p class="nav-text ">1 </p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text ">2</p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text ">3</p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text "> 4</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your HTML as well. CSS is only half of what we need to help you. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @disinfor I have did like u suggested and thank you for the welcoming into the community!

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Or some other CSS framework?

Comment: @disinfor I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues going on, mostly not overriding Bootstrap base styles.

1. By default, `.navbar .nav` is a flex item, and on smaller screens, it's `flex-direction` is `column` - so I set that to `row`
2. `.navbar .nav ul` is also a flex parent, and the flex direction was set to `column`, so I set that to row. And since `ul` isn't specific enough to overwrite bootstrap styles, I added the class selector `ul.navbar-nav` so it was more specific than bootstrap.
3. `ul.navbar-nav` is also a flex child so you can set it's `flex` properties (`flex: 1 1 100%`).
4. I also added some `margin` to your `li` items so you could see it working.
5. There is no reason for your `min-width: 400px` unless you have something going on below that for a different style. I removed it in my example, but you can certainly put it back in.

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    height: 54px
  }
  .navbar .nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar .nav ul.navbar-nav {
    padding-top: 5px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: smaller;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .navbar .nav ul.navbar-nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-primary">

  <a class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x35" width="40" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-1 h1">Byte Program</span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-3 mt-3 ">

      <li class="nav-item ">
        <p class="nav-text ">1 </p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text ">2</p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text ">3</p>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-text "> 4</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```